# How can I connect to a VPN and keep my internet connection with my second adaptor?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, networking, vpn, network-adapter

I have a WinXP with 2 network adapters and I sometimes need to connect to a VPN network. But When I do so, I loose my internet connection. This is not so bad if I'm at the office, but I remote in to my desktop via GoToAssist. As soon as I open the VPN, I loose the GoToAssist connection since I don't have Internet access when connected to the VPN.

Can I somehow connect to the VPN using network adaptor #1 and keep my internet connection with network adaptor #2?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an IPv4 route, to specify where you'd like specific traffic to go.

Unfortunately, I don't have enough time to get into the nitty-gritty of it right now, but...

**route /?**

**route PRINT**

Should give you some information to get you started.

Comment: This got it to work : http://serverfault.com/questions/139208/no-internet-access-while-being-connected-to-vpn-using-cisco-vpn-client-5

Comment: Also, I was using Shrew Soft, so I just modified the Policy to exclude the GoToAssist IPs and I can remote in even when connected to the VPN which is just enough!